# Soluble Linear Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group with a normal (invariant) series $1=G_n\leq ... \leq G_0=G$ whose factors are either torsion-free abelian group of finite rank, finite elementary abelian $p$-group or direct products of finitely many groups of type $p^\infty$. Now let $F$ be a generic factor of the series; $G/C_G(F)$ can be identified with a group of linear transformations of a finite dimensional vector space over the filed of rational numbers, the field $GF(p)$ or the field of $p$-adic numbers respectively. Moving to the algebraic closure of the field concerned and applying Mal'cev theorem ([Theorem 3.2.1](http://books.google.it/books?id=DPHMUeM_F2kC&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=mal%27cev%20theorem%20soluble%20linear%20group&source=bl&ots=b52GS8LzIm&sig=oDu5t5YbK48XZAhJxE0cqKl-oiY&hl=it&sa=X&ei=ysO6Uqm1I-bJygPU9YDQDA&ved=0CHMQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=mal%27cev%20theorem%20soluble%20linear%20group&f=false)) we conclude that $G/C_G(F)$ has a normal subgroup $C/C_G(F)$ of finite index whose derived group is unitriangulable.

The problem is now: it follows that $G$ has a normal subgroup $N$ (probabily the intersection of the $C$) with finite index such that $[G,N',...,N']={1}$? How?

In particular when we have an automorphism like $\alpha : C_{p^\infty} + C_{p^\infty} \longrightarrow C_{p^\infty} + C_{p^\infty} $ (here the sums are direct) we know that $\alpha$ can be rappresented with a 2x2 non-singular matrix over the $p$-adic integers and then of course by a linear transformation of the vector space of dimension 2 over the algebraic closure of the $p$ -adic numbers. If we know that in the last vector space there is a base such that the linear transformation can be expressed by unitriangular matrices, how can we come back with the information on the original map $\alpha$?

**References**

The problem is a part of the proof of Theorem 3.25 (p. 79, 80), *Finiteness Conditions and Generalized Soluble Groups* , D.J.S. Robinson.

Comment: I edited the question: trying to simplifying the question I made it nosense.

Comment: Cool. It makes sense to me now if the F are all finite. Presumably most of the same stuff works for your F as well.

Comment: Yeah the real problem (to me) is when F is a direct sum of Prufer groups. I cannot see how we can use the information about the unitriangularity of the linear transformation to say something on the automorphism $\alpha$ for instance.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand the problem exactly (my fault). Working as you say, we get that Fit=[G,N',N',...,N'] centralizes a "chief" series, so is a normal nilpotent subgroup, but I'm not sure what to do to finish it (Fit need not be finite index, and [G,Fit]=Fit is pretty common in finite groups).

Comment: I was working in the following way. Take $N$ to be the intersection of all $C$ such that $C/C_G(F)$ is the subgroup of finite index of $G/C_G(F)$ identified by the Mal'cev theorem. Now $N$ has finite index in $G$ and $N'$ SHOULD be such that $[G_i,N',..., N']\leq G_{i+1}$.

Comment: Infact, if $F$ is torsion free abelian of finite rank then we have that the automorphism induced by an element of $G/C_G(F)$ can be extended to one over $F\otimes \mathbb{Q}$ and then to the algebraic closure. Now by Mal'cev theorem the map we found is "unitrangular": this mean going back that $n^{-1}fn, f\in F, n\in N'$ is something like: $f$ multiplied by previous elements of the base in which we have the unitriangularity and so $[f,n_1,...,n_t]=1$ at some point. I hope this will be of some help.